# Theory of rotationally symmetric air cushion vehicle

Tags: fluid-mechanics, airflow, transportation, air, bernoulli

I am trying to develop a theory for this situation:
[image: Think of it like this: a blown-up balloon is attached to the center of a compact disc; you let it float as the balloon discharges]

A small blown-up balloon is attached to the center of a compact disc; you let it float as the balloon discharges. Simplifying assumptions: rotational symmetry, cushion has constant thickness t, stationary and incompressible flow, losses are negligible, ground is even and level, flow pressure and velocity are the same at positions 1 and 3. My attempt at a theory is here:
[Air Cushion Vehicle Theory](https://1drv.ms/w/s!AvoFL8QrGVaThotkQLFWU65BMtBp7Q?e=jkcsGU)
To begin with, I am interested in the relationship between vehicle weight W and air cushion thickness t. What I come up with is W = const1 - const2/t^2. That says that once a certain threshold thickness has been exceeded, the weight that the disc can carry increases with thickness t as it approaches a limiting value. Intuitively, that feels wrong; shouldn't a smaller thickness be able to carry more weight? I would be grateful for corrections to my thinking and approach, or for a reference to where this subject has already been treated.

Comment: Weight, pressure and flow rate... Only your static pressure at the walls holds your disk up. Bigger gap results in higher flow rate, and so higher dynamic pressure.  For a given power output, P, from your "balloon" (replace it with a weightless compressor and disk for now), and a given gap t, and disk diameter D, how much upward force do you get?

Comment: If you want the thing to "float" in a stable way, from a quasi-constant but unpredictable pressure source (balloon), then you'll want the pressure under the disc to be determined by a "pressure divider", i.e. two "resistors" in series. The upper resistance should be an orifice in the tube near location (1). The lower resistance is controlled by height (t) ... larger t -> less resistance ... thus the height will naturally vary (negative feedback) to bring the overall pressure at the divider to just enough to support the weight of the thing.

Comment: the key to this is getting an expression for the resistance, i.e. dp/dQ , between points (2) and (3) ...  [ p = pressure and Q = flow ] ... assume resistance in tube from (1) to (3) is negligible, and controlled by an orifice, which you need to add to the tube, and figure out the orifice size, to get reasonable values for the resulting equilibrium value of t